# CSS file is pending forever

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple nodejs (10.15.0) + express (^4.17.1) application inside a docker image. The app is serving a static HTML file.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="/css/third_party/jquery-ui.1.12.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
</head>
....
<body>
```

when accessing this HTML file the browser would hang forever to load the page. When checking the Network activity in Chrome I see such a picture
[image]

that css file hangs forever to be served.

the static file are configured to be served like this `app.use(express.static('./engine'));`

the more weird thing, if I use `curl localhost:1080/...css` that file comes immediately.

I am at loss here. Ideas?

Comment: Interesting. Does the same file hang outside the Docker container? Have you tried reproducing the browser's request exactly with `curl`?  You could also take a packet dump to see if there's anything fishy going on at the network level. Is it possible there is some middleware before `express.static` that is hanging (doesn't call `next()` in some cases)?

Comment: when the same project is used outside of Docker, all works as needed, strange indeed.

Comment: But you're serving your app from the same host and port as that CSS file, right? Does it work if you include the host:port in the `href`?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a workaround ?

Comment: I did, I had to use the "express-session" package, this solved the issue. But now I'm trying to use NGinx to serve the static files and remove NodeJS/express from the equation.